# Can not get .vue single file components to work with NWjs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, buefy

Good Afternoon, I am making a Desktop App using NWjs in its 0.26.1 version I am using Ubuntu server 16.04 with XfCE4 to develop the App I wanted to use Vue.JS for the data part and buefy for its UI Components. but since the this UI Vue Framework use single file .vue file components I am facing this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:600:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
at Module.load (module.js:555:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:518:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:510:3)
at Module.require (module.js:580:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at self.require (<anonymous>:11:26)
```

I've been able to use webpack to generate a bundle js file with no problems, but NWjs insist in parsing the HTML tags in the single file component.

The mockup component is as follows

```
 <template>
    <section>
    <span>
    <b-field>
        <b-switch v-model="bars">Bars</b-switch>
    </b-field>
    <b-datepicker inline v-model="date" :events="events" indicators="indicators">
    </b-datepicker>
    </span>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
</style>
```

Any light on this would be of invaluable help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove th `<style ` in `<style <style lang="sass" scoped>` i think it causes the problem

Comment: Excuse me , It was a typo of mine while pasting the code. the original was working fine in a django app. Is already edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Vue-cli and vue init.